# Непереведенная форма

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

После отправки запроса на рассмотрение тревоги к сообщению, при повторном открытии формы "тревога", появляется непереведенная форма "Вы уже отмечали данный вопрос тревогой".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]